# Grouping rows with condition

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
class Datacomponent(models.Model):
        id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        composition = models.ForeignKey(Composition, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Composition_ID', null=True, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        components = models.ForeignKey(Components, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Components_ID')  # Field name made lowercase.
        componentvalue = models.FloatField(db_column='ComponentValue')  # Field name made lowercase.



class Components(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

In `Datacomponent` there are multiple rows of same composition (which is foreign key to `Composition` table).

My end goal is to get set of `Composition` if each of its component values are in range of some values. In my approach shown below I do not get any composition_ids at all.

```
CompositionID   ComponentID  ComponentValue
   1               1            0.5
   1               2            0.3
   2               1            0.6
   2               2            0.4
   3               1            0.0
   3               2            0.1
```

So the query for above table would be: 'Get all composition ids with componentid=1 and componentvalue__range=(minn[a], maxx[b]). If we want comp value gte 0.5 for componentID 1 and gte 0.3 for componentID 2 our result should be just 2 because 2's component 1 is 0.6 and component2's value is 0.4.

Here's my approach which is not working:

```
    queries = [Q(componentvalue__range = (minn[v], maxx[v]),
                 components__name    = "'"+v+"'",
                ) for v in minn]

    query = queries.pop()
    for item in queries:
        query |= item

    composition_ids = Datacomponent.objects.filter(query).values_list('composition_id', flat=True)

    print (composition_ids.count())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then something like this may help

Edit after your comment. (I hope I understand you better this time). You're actually after `Composition` objects that have both comp1 and comp2 in within specified ranges(?) Then you can actually go about selecting them from `Composition` model.

First add a *related_name* to your `composition` field in `Datacomponent` model, something like "datacomp", for reverse queries.

```
from django.db.models import Q

class Datacomponent(models.Model):
    composition = models.ForeignKey(Composition, related_name='datacomp', ..) 
    ...

comp_1_query = Q(datacomp__components_id=YOUR_COMP1_ID, datacomp__componentvalue_range=(YOUR_RANGE1_MIN, YOUR_RANGE1_MAX)
comp_2_query = Q(datacomp__components_id=YOUR_COMP2_ID, datacomp__componentvalue_range=(YOUR_RANGE2_MIN, YOUR_RANGE2_MAX)


Composition.objects\
           .select_related('datacomp')\ # you can for optimization  
           .filter(comp_1_query, comp_2_query)\ # Simply 'and' since you want both to match
           .values_list('id', 'datacomp__components_id', 'datacomp__componentvalue', flat=True)
```

This should give you the compositions with component1 and component2 within specified ranges.

Comment: I think your solution is exactly what I have shown in the OP. The problem here is that if user inputs (0.5, 0.6) for component1 and (0.2, 0.3) for component2 both composition1 and composition2 would show up in result since we combined with an `or`. The desired result is just composition1 to be in the result since it matches both critereas.

Comment: I now understand your question better. You're actually after compositions that have both comp1 and comp2 in matching criteria? Edited the answer.